# cant see gridview data that I want to see

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

In my Project I need that user will see the garages that in the same city of user .

I created users table that include - `Id,UserName,Password,Email,CarModel,Year,City,`

and another Table is `GarageUsers` that include -`Id,UserName,Password,Email,Address,City,GarageName`.

In `Configure Data Source` I insertes this code :

```
 SELECT GargeUsers.GarageName, GargeUsers.Address,GargeUsers.City,GargeUsers.Email 
 FROM GargeUsers 
 INNER JOIN GarageuserCategory ON GargeUsers.Id = GarageuserCategory.UserId 
 I
 WHERE (GarageuserCategory.CategoryId = 1) AND (GargeUsers.City LIKE Users.City)
```

(The GarageUserCategory is to show the data in the current category- its Ok ignore it).

In this code I see the all garages.

I add Session that save the user city when the user login.
But I cant see what I want in gridview. I need to know how to equal the session (USerCity) to garage city.

```
protected void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from Users where UserName= '" + UserName.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select Password from Users where UserName= '" + UserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);

            string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");

            string UserCityQuery = "select City from Users where UserName= '" + UserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cityComm = new SqlCommand(UserCityQuery, conn);

            string UserCity = cityComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");



            if (password == Password.Text)
            {
                Session["UserCity"] = UserCity;


                Session["New"] = UserName.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password is not correct");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Write("User Name is not correct");

        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: I must to know some, maybe you can help me.   I must to Insert data In English or Its does not matter?

Comment: Try creating a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7358e/4) so we can see the data. The query looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I need that user will see the garages that in the same city of user.

That seem like you need a filter to select `USER`

Also you say

> (The GarageUserCategory is to show the data in the current category- its Ok ignore it).

So i remove it. Next time try make the query simple with only the problem you have

```
SELECT 
    GargeUsers.GarageName, 
    GargeUsers.Address,
    GargeUsers.City,
    GargeUsers.Email 
FROM 
    GargeUsers INNER JOIN         
    Users ON GargeUsers.City = Users.City 
WHERE 
    Users.UserID = @userID <-- ADD THIS ONE
```

To handle variable in SQL check [SELECT @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187330(v=sql.120).aspx)

To select the cities garage after user Select a city in the page

```
SELECT 
    GargeUsers.GarageName, 
    GargeUsers.Address,
    GargeUsers.City,
    GargeUsers.Email 
FROM 
    GargeUsers 
WHERE 
    GargeUsers.City = @cityID
```

Comment: Hello.
I explain - The user insert his city and the other feilds (email, car,.....)           also the garage user.                                                                                     When user enter , and choose category, he shoukd see the garages in is city.  so I think maybe to filter ther garage city not user. Or Im wrong?

Comment: Or maybe filter users and garage city?

Comment: I try what you wrote me, but i get error messege "Must declare the scalar variable "@userID"

Comment: Now I get "cannot verify queries which contain parameters"

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question. Now I guess you are creating a `CREATE USER` page. And after user select `CITY` you want show available garage so user select one?

Comment: Please can you explain what you have and what you need with more detail?

Comment: I create a create user page and create grage user page,                               User can chose a category car problem, and when user choose a category he should to see the garages that registered , and from the same city.   I think that i need to show you my site project, maybe add me at facebook - Elishay Luzon. (I need help very much , I stuck and I need to continue, because Its College final project.

Comment: We can help if you have a specific question. We cant do homework and we arent free programers. Read a tutorial. I recomend this one for [MVC](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v) That channel also have tutorials for ASP and SQL

Comment: I dont want that you do my homework.  I just want to show you what i need to do . Hard for me to explain it all here in one question.